# how can you express multiple <options> in xpath?

Tags: ruby, xpath

for multiple selectdown form, how can you express multiple options selected ?

```
  <select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Chocolate</option>
    <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
    <option>Taffy</option>
    <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
    <option>Fudge</option>
    <option>Cookie</option>
  </select>
```

`/html/body/form/select/option[1],option[2],option[3]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but wouldn't this be:

```
/html/body/form/select/option[@selected='selected']
```

Update: Based on your comment, would you not need something like:

```
/html/body/form/select/option[@val = '1' or @val = '3']
```

(though your example select doesn't have any `val` attributes)

Comment: actually i should've been more clear. i dont just want the selected options. i want the other options as well.

what i want is a way to select multiple options.

     /html/body/form/select/option[@val = '1'],option[@val = '3']

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
/html/body/form/select/option[1] | /html/body/form/select/option[2]
```

The pipe character ("|") join two sets, removing duplicate ones

Answer (score 1):

maybe rather like "/html/body/form/select/option[@selected='selected']"

Comment: actually i should've been more clear. i dont just want the selected options. i want the other options as well.

what i want is a way to select multiple options.

     /html/body/form/select/option[@val = '1'],option[@val = '3']